# Download a webpage that fetches content with script

Tags: php, jquery, wget

I would like to get the page content from https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/8304486/dashboard
I am not able to use php `file_get_contents` .

I also tried

```
wget -r https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/8304486/dashboard
```

That doesn't work either.

Also tried to use jQuery .

```
$("#divcontent").load("https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/8304486/dashboard");
```

That also doesn't work. Any idea how can I get this webpage?

Comment: Have you tried a different url? Some sites like google, will not let your scrape their site. In some cases you'll want to add an agent in your header...etc

Comment: I can download other pages like `www.google.com` but I want to download this particular page and similar ones.

Answer (score 0):

Content on this page loading via ajax. The url from which it is loaded is `https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/8304486/dashboard/ContestInfo`
so you can try

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/8304486/dashboard/ContestInfo');
print_r($data);
?>
```

to get the content

Comment: didn't you try that?

Comment: I tried that. I get the JSON with 4 Problems from the content part of the page https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/8304486/dashboard

Did I understand your question wrong? You need something else?

Comment: open the page in browser and see if you got exactly same thing

Comment: Can you specify what specific content you need to get?

Comment: I want problem statements

Comment: including the css structure